# How many objects are created (string pool+heap)

Tags: java

```
String s = new String("a");
    s.concat("b");
    s.concat("c");
```

As far as I understand, the no. of counts :

In pool - 3 ("a", "b", "c")

In heap - 3 ("a", "ab", "ac"), where "ab" and "ac" are eligible for garbage collection.

Am I right ?

I have this confusion.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

- 3 objects in constant pool ("a","b","c"). All literals and
- 3 in heap since String is immutable. Each `concat` creates a String
  object.

Total of 6.

Comment: suppose we make string s1 = new string("abc"); and string pool does not contain "abc" object.. so when compile this line does it make 2 objects for the same line as one is inside heap memory and other one is inside string pool? am I correct?